# php make an array list for matching id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have my table like this

```
id categories
1  80|98|22|6|76|1|24|129|59|73|7|40|85|35|42|126|81|37|128|147|106
2  15|85|49|22|6
```

You can see I have categories id in the table separted by | . I have an another table with those categories name. I want to get all the categories and make them an array.  So far now  I did like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "listings";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$listing_array = array();
$category_array = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM `listings` ORDER by listing_id";
    $category_array = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $categories = $obj->categories;
  }
    foreach( $category_array as $category_names ) {
         $test = explode('|', $category_names);
    }


  $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

After this how can I get the categories name and make them an array for the rows?

Comment: Post table schema of categories table too..

Comment: Dont save data like that joins will be nightmarish

Comment: the categories table has the id and name only. Thats all

Comment: Stop. See normalisation. Go.

Comment: Can't you join the categories table to listings and merely iterate through the result set?

Comment: Edwin Codd quite unhappy

Comment: Why are you setting `$category_array` as an empty array twice? Also you are using it on a foreach without change it's value, so the foreach will not do anything. `$test` and `$categories` are being reseted on each iteration and their value are being useless..

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `listings` ORDER by listing_id";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $categories =array();
   $cat = explode("|",$obj->categories);
    $querycat = "SELECT CategoryName FROM `category` where category_id in '".$cat."'";
      while($objcat = $resultcat ->fetch_object())
      {
        array_push($categories,$objcat ->CategoryName); 
     }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `where in` instead of using multiple selects?

Comment: yes. we can also use that. but seeing the code structure, its of basic format. So i suggest this one

Comment: Sometimes people try to help out the database engine thinking it can't optimize a better query

Comment: This may give you performance issues though. If you have 15 ids on `$cat` this code will run 15 selects, when it could be only one. Also, your  `$categories` will get only the values from the last iteration of the while.

Comment: Php one of the slowest platforms. How about 1500 categories

Comment: @AsConfused then why don't you put your suggestion here for this question?

Comment: Looking forward to up voting yours which i will )

Comment: @sujivasagam I did not because I thought that you could just edit your answer. You have just a little issue on it.

Comment: @ Gabriel Moretti & @AsConfused ok now or need any change?

Comment: Refer to @uchiha single query